# What is the difference between two types of tutoring?

Tags: football-manager-2014

There are two options when tutoring players: off the pitch and improve game. What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The off the field one will help with their mental attributes, while the improve game helps with the technical side of the game.

Make sure to use a player with high determination as your tutor when choosing the off-field option.

Comment: What about personality? It is included in off the field then, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, personality is the off-field one.